# PHP imap_search no search results

Tags: php, imap

$some = imap_search($mbox, "TEXT \"{$q}\" ");

where $q - some sring query

but I haven't results if $q string in body, but results are present if $q is in the subject.

What may cause such behaviour? Server settings?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the TEXT option.
Try to use BODY and SUBJECT options.

Comment: BODY option provide the same "no results" behaviour